# PHP 5.4.13 "procedure entry point could not be located in the dll php5ts.dll"

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, php5

I did a manual install of PHP 5.4.13 on Windows Server 2008 R2 on D drive.

Today I tried to run a script directly using php.exe through the command line but got two error pop up windows:

```
The procedure entry point php_set_error_handling could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dll
The procedure entry point php_checkuid could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dll
```

Then, I realized there is an old PHP 5.2 in C:\Program Files, so I removed that. And then, I get errors on the command line:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\php5\ext\php_gd2.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\php5\ext\php_mbstring.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\php5\ext\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Directive 'allow_call_time_pass_reference is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0
```

C:\php5 never existed, and has no relevance to my PHP 5.4 on D drive.
And, the PHP 5.4 path is the first one in the `PATH` environment variable.

However, accessing .php files through Apache is fine.

Any help is appreciated.